# Bluemix のアプリ実行環境でのディスク

Tags: bluemix

アプリケーション実行環境ではライブラリを自由に追加できるようなのですが、その際に使用するディスクについては、別にDBサービスを追加して使用するということになりますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

”ディスク”が意味しているところによるかと思いますが、DBとして利用するスペースが欲しい場合には、DBサービスを選択す必要があると思います。

揮発性（停止時に消えることを前提とするのであれば）で良ければランタイムの起動時にメモリに応じてストレージスペースが提供されます。